# Solutions of two minimisation problems

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Let $\mathcal{X}\equiv \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x=y\}$. Take the function
$$
(x,x)\in \mathcal{X} \mapsto f(g(x), x)\in \mathbb{R}^+_0,
$$
where $\mathbb{R}^+_0$ is the set of positive reals including zero.

Assume that:

(1) $f(g(3),3)=0$. This means that $f(g(x),x)$ achieves its minimum when $x=3$.

(2) $3\underbrace{=}_{\text{unique solution!}} \text{argmin}_x f(g(3), x)$.

**Question**: does this imply that
$$
3\underbrace{=}_{\text{unique solution!}} \text{argmin}_x f(g(x), x)
$$
? If not, under which conditions we can claim so (like continuity, etc.)?

Comment: Can you please clarify with regard to (2) -- do you mean that there is only one point $x_0$ such that (2) holds? Or do you mean that (1) holds for any such $x_0$ satisfying (2), where the minimum on the Righthand side of (2) is achieved uniquely?

Comment: $x_0$ is a SPECIFIC point on the real line. For instance, $x_0=3$. (1) means that $f(g(3), 3)=0$. (2) means that 3 is the unique minimiser with respect to $x$ of $f(g(3), x)$. I have reformulated my question by replacing $x_0$ with $3$, for clarity.

Comment: No. Consider for simplicity: i) $g$ to be the identity (for simplicity); ii) f(x,x)=0 for all $x$ and strictly positive everywhere else (e.g., the function given by shifting the parabola across the diagonal $\mathcal{X}$, which happens to be smooth and convex). Then, (1) and (2) is fulfilled but the uniqueness in your question fails. I would say that a sufficient condition should be strict convexity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we set $f(a,b)=|b-3|-a$ and $g(a)=a$, then certainly $3$ is the unique minimizer of $\min_{b\in\mathbb{R}}\;f(g(3),b)$. However, when we consider minimizing the general function $f(g(a),a)$, [we can see graphically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/se2fvgd0yk) that while $3$ is indeed a minimizer, it is **no longer unique**.

I am not aware of an equivalent condition, but a sufficient condition would be that $f(g(\cdot),\cdot)$ is [strongly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions) (uniformly convex, strictly convex, or convex+supercoercive would also be fine here, since they also guarantee uniqueness).